# JQuery patterns and best practices in Asp.net MVC 3.0

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, jquery

I'm working with an Asp.net MVC 3.0 application and use JQuery + JSON . I'm planing to use jquery post and get methods to send/back data to server.As a result, my JQuery Code base will be large and should be maintainable.

so that what are the best practices and design patterns when using JQuery with ASP.net MVC 3.0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a few tips:

- Always try to place javascript in separate js files and avoid placing it in views.
- Never hardcode urls in your javascript files. Always use Url helpers when generating urls.
- For javascript code that could be reused in multiple places, prefer to write a [jQuery plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring).
- Before writing some code, search whether someone hasn't yet written a jQuery plugin for it.
- Minify your javascript files when running in release mode
- Try to reduce the number of AJAX requests: for example prefer one AJAX request which sends/receives bigger data compared to multiple AJAX requests with smaller data.

Comment: in addition you should make a single js file. Here are some other good advices, http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2011/07/22/review-open-source-components-used-in-learnknockoutjs/  http://www.hanselman.com/blog/NerdDinnerBeingUpdatedToMVC3WithRazorHTML5GeoLocationEFCodeFirstJQueryMobileYepNopeAndModernizrAndAFixedMobileDeviceCapabilitiesViewEngine.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed:+ScottHanselman+%28Scott+Hanselman+-+ComputerZen.com%29